# Retrieving ZBar Data

Tags: php, api, imagemagick, barcode, zbar

I am trying to develop a program on a Windows environment that can interpret bar code data scanned from ZBar.  I have ZBar installed and working, and it currently displays scanned bar code data on a cmd-type output.  The difficulty I'm having is that I can't figure out how to retrieve it with another program (PHP) or store it in a database.  Any thoughts on how I might access data scanned from ZBar?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `system()` function in PHP:

```
$barcode = system('zbarimg scan.jpg', $retval);
```

[Link for system() documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

That will allow you to grab the output of `zbar` and use it as you wish - you can then put it in a database using some PHP.

Or, if you want to add it to a database like `sqlite` at the command line, you can create a database with a suitable table like this:

```
sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> create table barcodes (id integer primary key autoincrement, code text);
sqlite> .q
```

then insert a barcode like this:

```
ECHO INSERT INTO BARCODES VALUES ^(NULL,"1234567890^"^); | sqlite3 test.db
```

Or, if you want to parse the output of `zbar`, you can use this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%L IN (`ZBAR IMAGE.JPG`) DO (
   ECHO %%L
   ECHO INSERT INTO BARCODES VALUES ^(NULL,^"%%L^"^); | sqlite3 test.db
)
REM Show user what is now in database
sqlite3 test.db "select * from barcodes"
```